# How to change font to bold/underline/italics in Python Tkinter listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

How do I change the font style of an item in a listbox? I assumed it would use `listbox[i].itemconfig()`, but [THIS](https://kite.com/python/docs/Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig) implies font style is not an option.

I also read [THIS](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-September/484117.html), which implies you have to first get the font of the item, then change it and set it to the new font. But how do I do this with a single item in a listbox?

I am trying to have a button to set the selected item in a listbox as a 'master' (not important what that means), which for these purposes just needs to be highlighted in some way (preferably not with foreground/background/whatever colors). Below is my attempt, which does not at all work, because it is incomplete. I am unsure how to interact with the fonts of specific items in a listbox. Please feel free to offer better approaches.

I apologize for not providing more or better example code. I do not know how to attempt this. I am also using [THIS](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/font.htm#M28) as a reference. (I am having a hard time understanding `tkFont` as a package, and why/how it should be used over `tk.font`...)

```
def set_master(self):
    the_selection = self.the_listbox.curselection()
    for the_index, the_item in enumerate(self.the_listbox):
        f = tkFont.Font(font=the_item.cget("font"))

        if int(the_selection) == int(the_index):
            f.configure(underline=True, weight='bold', slant='italic')
        else:
            f.configure(underline=False, weight='normal', slant='roman')

        #the_item.set_font(f)  <--This is pseudocode
    return
```

Comment: I don't think you can change the font of a single item with tkinter, only the whole listbox. also the tkinter.font module is a wrapper for tk/tcl tkfont, so its the same thing with a python interface

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the font of an individual item in a listbox.

If you need something that works like a listbox but which offers the ability to change the font of individual items, you can use the `ttk.Treeview` widget.